# How to match a URL in this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen various articles which show how to match a URL. But my situation is a bit different from the usual URL matching.

[This](http://regexr.com/37i6s) was one such regex that didn't work for me

```
/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/
```

**My requirement:**

My requirement is that I've a string like this

**userlist.2011.text_mediafire.com**,

**userlist.2011.text_http://www.mediafire.com**",

**userlist.2011.text_http://mediafire.com**",

**userlist.2011.text.www.mediafire.com**

Now, I want to match **mediafire.com** along with (if exists) "**`http://www.`**" and "**www.**" so, the contraint that I wish to set is that all the strings to the left of a TLD (in this case '.com') should be recorded upto a list of specal characters like `'"_-` etc.

I wasn't able to proceed any further except that the basic `/(.*)\.(com|net|org|info)/` .Which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^'"_.-]*\.(?:com|net|org|info)\b)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as expectd but how do I make an exclusion for the special char '.' when there is a 'www.'? I'll made an edit to the question

Comment: For instance : userlist.2011.text.www.mediafire.com doesnt work as per the above regex

Comment: Perfect! I seemed to have run into another complication. What if there is a subdomain?  userlist.2011.text.www.torentz.3xforum.ro.avi

Answer (score 0):

You need the `'$'` to match the end of string.  If you care about capturing the entire string before the special character you will also need to match the beginning of the string `'^'`.

```
/^(.*)\.(([^\.]+)\.(com|net|org|info))$/
```

Comment: Hi chrissy, I don't think your answer works for the above edit that I made.

Comment: /^(http:\/\/)*www\.[^_-]*(.*)\.(com|net|org|info)$/

Comment: Nope, still won't work. This does not work if www. isn't present in the string